# nginx giving 403 when trying to cache css / js etc

Tags: nginx

When I try to cache static files for the user, using

```
   location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|bmp|ttf|tof|svg|swf)$ {
       expires max;
       access_log off;
       error_log off;
    }
```

The static files do not load (and give 403 Forbidden when accessed), so my site loads without any of those static files. When I comment out that part, everything works as should.

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Maybe post a link to your full config. On a different point, these Nginx configs with long lists of static files found on the web have been outdated for almost two years now.

Comment: What's happening is that whenever I target any of those files through regex, it gives a 403 Foridden error. I replaced the query to just \.css$ and the images are loading fine now, just the css gives a 403 error.

Comment: After more testing, it doesn't even have to be regex - I made a full path the main wordpress css file, and that is still being 403ed. I chmod'd it to 0777 and made the group www-data which nginx is using into the owner

Answer (score 1):

It's maybe because you don't specify any root directive in outer contexts (e.g. server block).

if you add a root directive to the server block or location block with path to your static folder it will be fixed:

```
server{
    .
    .
    .
    root /path/to/static/folder;

    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|bmp|ttf|tof|svg|swf)$ {

       # or add a root directive here
       root /path/to/static/folder;

       expires max;
       access_log off;
       error_log off;
    }
}
```